# HMatrix (Haskell) => Cannot run Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Tests.runTests on Windows 7

Tags: haskell

I installed hmatrix, hmatrix-tests using the instruction given on [Installation page](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/blob/master/INSTALL.md). However I always get this error:

i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\hmatrix-0.16.0.6\HShmatrix-0.16.0.6.o: unknown symbol `_asinh'

Please let me know how this can be fixed.

Comment: When do you get this error? At what point

Comment: While libraries are loading.

Comment: This is a linker error. Compile with `-v3` to see the exact arguments that are being give to `ld`.

Comment: gcc.exe "-U__i686" "-fno-stack-protector"
"-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE" "-Lcabal\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\hmatrix-0.16.0.6" "--pri
nt-file-name" "blas.dll"

Comment: Similalry for lapack.dll